# Is it possible to connect an external CD/DVD drive to an iOS device?

Tags: ios, optical-drive

What happens to those people who have completely switched to an iOS device and don't have a CD drive? Then, when they want to rip a CD/DVD to their iOS device, they can't. Is it possible to connect an external CD/DVD drive to an iOS device?

Comment: so its not possible to read the DVD file from an IOS device directly even if I have access to the DMG everywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is no way to interface a CD drive with an iOS device. The best way to do this is to have your iOS device registered to a copy of iTunes running on a Mac or PC, and to connect the iOS device to the Mac or PC via WiFi or a USB cable. This would presuppose that you have a suitable CD drive connected to the Mac or PC for ripping audio.

However, it occurs to me that you could probably rip music to AAC or MP3 format on a Mac or PC and then email those files to yourself, check the email on your iOS device, and then open the email attachments on the iOS device. That would get the music files in there.

Comment: so its not possible to read the DVD file from an IOS device directly even if I have access to the DMG everywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the only Apple-supported interface adapter between an iPad and a CD/DVD/optical drive is a Mac or PC running iTunes.